# Share Public Key between two devices over network [RSA]

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

I am working with `Asymmetric Cryptography (RSA & ECC)`. I have a very fundamental question when it comes to public key exchange or at least my understanding of the mechanism.

**Considerations**

- client called C1
- server called S1
- algorithm: RSA (asymmetric)
- threat: Man in the Middle
- objective: transfer of sensitive information over the network (can be data or symmetric keys for hybrid encription)

**What I've read so far**

1. C1 creates a pair of RSA keys and makes an API call sending in the public key to S1.
2. On getting a request with the client's public key the server (S1) generates a RSA key pair and sends it back to the client (C1).
3. Now that the key's have now been transferred, C1 encrypts the data (cipher text) using the server's public key, sign's the cipher text with client's private key and makes an API call.
4. The server receives the request that contains the cipher text, uses the client's public key to validate signature, uses the server private key to decrypt the data, performs some operations, generates the response, encrypts the response using the client's public key, signs the response cipher text with server private key and returns the response.

**How can the Man in The Middle Attack is possible?**

1. in the initial call, let's say the hacker intercepts the first call that the client (C1) makes, generates a RSA key pair and sends the server the Hacker's public key instead.
2. The server returns back the server public key and the hacker intercepts the server response and stores the server's public key and then returns hacker's public key to the client.
3. The client assumes the Hacker's public key is in fact the server's public key, encrypts the data, signs it and sends it back.
4. The hacker intercepts that call as well and it decrypts the data, modifies it and encrypts it with the server public key, signs it with Hacker's private key and sends it to the server.
5. The server verifies the cipher text and tries to decrypt it and it all works since the server has hacker's public registered as the client's public key.

> Now this out to be very easy to crack, the hacker (Man in the Middle) can read sensitive information and can also modify the request that can lead to malicious operations on the application server.

I am sure I am missing something in this flow since RSA and such interaction is so widely used. Can someone please point out what have I missed and if I haven't missed out anything, how can I protect the system against such attacks

Comment: You're basically correct, your scheme is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks because neither party is authenticated to the other. The countermeasure is to get your key *certified*, e.g. by a certification authority (CA). The CA's key also needs be authenticated as you get nothing for free. This is accomplished by pre-bundling the CA key (or keys from many CAs) with the software. You must still trust that the software has not been tampered with prior to your receiving it. There are many more details to be understood of course, which makes the question probably too broad for SO.

Comment: @JamesKPolk thank you for validating the threat. I had considered the CA approach but I had a concern about certificate pinning considering that the chain of trust can also be broken.I can understand that the resolution might be too broad for SO but if you comment a few links and some jargons that I can look up for a more deeper understanding that would lead me to the resolution of my concerns it'll be of great help. PS I can quickly connect the dots. Maybe once I go through some pointers that you lay down I would be better equipped to ask a more narrow question. I'd really appreciate the help